# My regex does not remove the dash between numbers in java

Tags: java, regex

I have tried to use regex in JAVA for replacing any funny character in a string for mobile numbers, however, it doesnt seems to be able to remove the '-' between the numbers

here is my code,

```
// Remove all (,),-,.,[,],<,>,{,} from string

myMobileNumber.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```

example 65-12345678

it will still allows the - to go through without deleting it away. =(

Answer (score 5):

You should reassign the result. A String is an immutable object, and all methods including `.replaceAll` won't modify it.

```
myMobileNumber = myMobileNumber.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```

(BTW, the pattern `"\\D"` is equivalent to `"[^\\d]"`.)